# What Mechanisms does Tensorflow Provide for Managing Model Input Parameters?

Tags: tensorflow

I am really not sure, whether this question has not already been answered. But I did not find it. Maybe I just don't know the terms to find it.

To create a model in Tensorflow I do the following two steps

I create the model:

```
def my_model(x, weights, biases):
    # 1. Hidden layer
    layer_1 = tf.matmul(x, weights["h1"])
    layer_1 = tf.add(layer_1, biases["b1"])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1, name="a1")

    # 2. Hidden layer
    layer_2 = tf.matmul(layer_1, weights["h2"])
    layer_2 = tf.add(layer_2, biases["b2"])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2, name="a2")

    # Output layer
    out_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights["h3"]), biases["b3"], name="a3")

    return out_layer
```

I create dictionaries where I save the weights and biases:

```
weights = {
    "h1": tf.get_variable("h1", initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer),
    "h2": tf.get_variable("h2", initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer),
    "h3": tf.get_variable("h3", initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer),
    }

biases = {
    "b1": tf.get_variable("b1", shape=[n_hidden_1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer),
    "b2": tf.get_variable("b2", shape=[n_hidden_2], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer),
    "b3": tf.get_variable("b", shape=[n_classes], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
    }
```

I would like to know if there is a way where I just provide a list with network parameters like:

`network_parameters = [n_input, n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2, n_classes]`

where `n_inuput`, `n_hidden_1` etc. are numbers, to create a model. That would be great for larger models. How do I do that?

Comment: I can empathize with your struggle! You *could* load an array with parameters and then call individual elements (network_parameters[1] for example) but that would make the code a little harder to read. Imagine troubleshooting a shape mismatch with array elements instead of meaningful variable names! As one answer states, TF Estimators provide a way to manage input parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into tensorflow's [estimators](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/estimators), for example [`DNNClassifier`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.6/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier). They are precisely there to simplify model creation.

Example:

```
estimator = DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=[categorical_feature_a_emb, categorical_feature_b_emb],
    hidden_units=[1024, 512, 256],
    optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
      learning_rate=0.1,
      l1_regularization_strength=0.001
    ))
```